# Can I create this json format from my dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have to following dataframe:

```
ID . Desc . pID . reCost . rpCost . Hrs .     Mns .    Sds .  sID . sTime . tID

12    text    13    28       13       {12,12}   {20,20} {32,12} 12  2312  33
```

Hrs, Mns, Sds are a set of 1 or 2 numbers

I am trying to create a json that takes the above df and looks like this:

```
{"ID":12,

 "Desc":text,

 "pID":13,

 "time":{"Hrs":[12,12],"Mns":[32,12],"Sds":[32,12]},

 "cost":[{"reCost":28,"rpCost":13,"tID":33}]

}
```

is this possible in pandas?

Comment: `df.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')` ?

Comment: @mad_ for this specific problem when I use df.to_json() my jupyter notebook crashes.  Everytime.  Anyway,I also don't think there is a way to get my desired output with that function.

Comment: You have to group you time-related columns in one and cost related in one. Then you can try the above code. If you provide an example to create your dataframe I can give it a try.